# Cannot authenticate with Twitter using Expo

Tags: react-native, twitter, oauth-2.0, expo, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use OAuth2 to authenticate with Twitter on my React-Native/Expo app, using the [expo-auth-session](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) package ([Expo's guide for Twitter OAuth](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#twitter)).

The Twitter OAuth2 flow works in two steps : first the user authorizes the app to access their account, which returns a code, then we exchange that code for an access token.
I am stuck at the second step.
Whenever I try to exchange the code for a token, using expo's *exchangeCodeAsync* function with these parameters :

```
exchangeCodeAsync({
    clientId: '<CLIENT_ID>',
    redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: 'my.app',
        useProxy
    }),
    code: response.params.code,
    extraParams: {
        client_id: "<CLIENT_ID>",
        code_verifier: request?.codeVerifier || '',
        redirect_uri: makeRedirectUri({
            scheme: 'my.app',
            useProxy
        }),
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
    },
}, discovery)
```

I get this error :

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```

What I understand is that the function makes a request to the /oauth2/token route of the Twitter API under the hood, but because of some wrong parameter it returns an HTML error code :

> Something went wrong, but don’t fret — let’s give it another shot.

Since the error message is so vague, I have no idea of what is wrong with my request.

I assume that since I have completed the authorization step, the redirect_uri is properly configured. I have also made sure that the format for the "code_verifier" and "code" fields were valid, according to [Twitter's documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token).

Here is an Expo Snack to show the complete App.js setup I am using (I've also configured app.json with a custom scheme )

https://snack.expo.dev/lWYp82Pwq

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a working Twitter login using a bit of a cobbled-together code path:

```
const twitterDiscovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: "https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize",
  tokenEndpoint: "https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token",
}
...
    const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
      scheme: APP_URI_SCHEME,
      useProxy: true,
    })
    const reqConfig = {
      clientId: TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      redirectUri,
      usePKCE: true,
      scopes: twitterScopes,
    }
    const authReq = new AuthRequest(reqConfig)
    const authUrl = await authReq.makeAuthUrlAsync(twitterDiscovery)
    const loginResult = await AuthSession.startAsync({ authUrl, returnUrl })
    if (loginResult.type !== "success") {
      throw new Error("...")
    }
    const tokenRequest = new AccessTokenRequest({
      ...reqConfig,
      code: loginResult.params.code,
      extraParams: {
        code_verifier: authReq.codeVerifier,
      },
    })
    const tokenResult = await tokenRequest.performAsync(twitterDiscovery)
```

This could obviously be cleaned up a bit, but it does appear to be functional, so I wanted to post even though it's not pretty.