# JSON Parse error occurs in "expo-auth-session"

Tags: react-native, expo, twitter-oauth, expo-auth-session

I am developing Twitter authentication with ReactNative.
I am using the "expo-auth-session" library.
When executing "tokenRequest.performAsync(discovery)" with the code below, the following error occurs.
What is the cause?

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: <

```
import {makeRedirectUri, useAuthRequest, AccessTokenRequest} from 'expo-auth-session';

...

const discovery = {
  authorizationEndpoint: "https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize",
  tokenEndpoint: "https://twitter.com/2/oauth2/token",
  revocationEndpoint: "https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/revoke",
};

const reqConfig = {
  clientId: TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
  redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
    scheme: 'xx.xx.xx',
    path: 'twitter/callback',
  }),
  usePKCE: true,
  scopes: [
    'tweet.read',
    'tweet.write',
    'offline.access',
  ],
};

const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
  {...reqConfig},
  discovery,
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (response?.type === 'success') {
    const {code, state} = response.params;

    const tokenRequest = new AccessTokenRequest({
      ...reqConfig,
      code,
      extraParams: {
        code_verifier: request.codeVerifier,
        state,
      },
    });

    (async() => {
      try {
        const tokenResult = await tokenRequest.performAsync(discovery);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    })();
  }
}, [response]);

return (
  <View>
    <Button onPress={() => promptAsync} title={'login'}></Button>
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just based off `JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: <` it looks like HTML is being parsed as JSON. When this happens double check any HTTP endpoints and make sure the `Content-Type` header is being passed.

See if you can dump the `response` object into a log, and also take a look at what's defined in `tokenRequest` before calling `performAsync`.

This looks related: [Cannot authenticate with Twitter using Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73821418/851230)

Comment: Content-Type was "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
I think the content defined in tokenRequest is also correct, but I get an error.